# Alternative to geom_flag (ggflags)

Tags: r, ggplot2, point, flags

I've noticed that the {ggflags} package is no longer supported in R. Does anybody know if there's an alternative for plotting points as country flags as it could've been done with geom_flag?

Answer (score 0):

ggflags has never been officially supported (meaning available on a formal archive like CRAN) - it's a package in github, basically in eternal development.

There are two versions of ggflags around: One with round flags (https://github.com/jimjam-slam/ggflags) and one with rectangle flags (https://github.com/ellisp/ggflags).

Your options: you could fork into that repository in github and update it to work for later versions of R, e.g. with a pull request or you just keep your own version of it. This certainly requires a certain knowledge of how to write packages (I've learned that with Hadley's help: https://r-pkgs.org/). You will do the community a great service, I honestly encourage you to do so:)

Or, if you feel open for some risks, you could download the package and just update the description file by removing unwanted dependencies. Code might fail, but there is a chance that it will work. Don't worry, you won't kill your computer doing that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30564896/7941188 tells you how to do this.

Comment: Ha, I did not understand a word of what you're saying (but thank you anyways) :). Is there a way I can simply use an old version of it or something?